# when to precompile a website?

Tags: asp.net

Hi
What are the practical advantages of precompiling a website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/399f057w%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> ASP.NET can also precompile an entire
>   site before it is made available to
>   users. This provides a number of
>   advantages, including:
>
> Faster response time for users, since
>   pages and code files do not have to be
>   compiled the first time they are
>   requested. This is particularly useful
>   on large sites that are updated
>   frequently.
>
> A means to identify compile-time bugs
>   before users see a site.
>
> The ability to create a compiled
>   version of the site that can be
>   deployed to a production server
>   without source code.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Precompilation Overview - MSDN

> You can precompile a Web site project
>   before it is made available to users.
>   This provides many advantages, which
>   include
>
> - faster initial response time,
> - error checking,
> - source-code protection and
> - efficient deployment.   This is particularly important in large sites
>     where there are frequent changes in
>     Web pages and code files.

Comment: When you copy documentation, I think you should use blockquote and post a link for more info.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know the main advatage is perfomance of the first hit to a page in the site.

Comment: granted, specially when you modify the code on the web site directly and not using automated deploy from a build env.